# Trying to code a Linear Regression oscillator in Trading View?

Tags: tradingview-api

`enter code here`
`enter code here`inputs:
`enter code here`Price(close),
`enter code here`Length(20),
`enter code here`Displace( 0 );

`enter code here`variables:
`enter code here`Avg(0),
`enter code here`Momo(0),
`enter code here`DML(0),
`enter code here`LR(0),
`enter code here`oLRSlope( 0 ),
`enter code here`oLRAngle( 0 ),
`enter code here`oLRIntercept( 0 ),
`enter code here`oLRValue( 0 ) ;

`enter code here`Avg = AverageFC( Price, Length ) ;
`enter code here`DML = (Highest(High, 20) + Lowest(Low, 20)) /2;
`enter code here`Momo = close - (( DML + Avg) / 2);
`enter code here`LR = linearreg(momo, length, 0, oLRSlope, oLRAngle, oLRIntercept, `enter code here`oLRValue);

`enter code here`Plot1( oLRValue, !( "oLRValue" ),yellow );
`enter code here`end;

`enter code here`Plot4( 0, !( "ZeroLine" ), darkgray );

Comment: I coded this in Easy Language Trade Station and can't get in Trading View. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I want to take this code I had for Trade Station and create an indicator in Trading View. Thanks!